# Convert Raw JSON response to image

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, response

I have a server response which is in json format and I have an image sent as a raw data in the response. I want to convert it into image and put it in the imageView that I have. The value for the image in json response is :

> "storedisplayimage" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQy419TQ6bt9rpJqkugoopy9sQ3R2vzzOTjkMqK3mb

Comment: Is this a base64 encoded image? If so, check again if you pasted it correctly

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

store what JSON throws you so you can displayed later while convert

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let userImage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "PictureFromJson")
        let imageBase64 = ConduPerfilViewController.convertBase64ToImage(imageString: userImage!)
        viewphoto.image = imageBase64
}
```

convert JSON base64 to IMG

```
//convert base64ToImage
    class func convertBase64ToImage(imageString: String) -> UIImage {
        let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        return UIImage(data: imageData)!
    }
```

Comment: The question is not related to any of the delegates and the answer is not related to JSON parsing.